# Displaying JSON content in table rows using angularjs and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, codeigniter

I'm just trying to fetch contents from server and display it in a table using Angularjs. I'm been trying this from a while, but did not got any solution yet. Btw, I'm working on CodeIgniter framework.

Here is my CodeIgniter controller;

```
public function list_agents() {
    if($this->is_logged_in ()) {
        $agents = $this->generic_model->general_fetch('agent_master');
        echo json_encode($agents);
    }
    else {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

In the above code, instead of echo I used print, print_r also.. But still its not working.

Here is my js file function;

```
(function () {
var addApp = angular.module('agentApp', ['ngRoute']);
addApp.controller('agentAddController', function ($scope, $http, growl) {
$scope.receivedData = [];
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'agent/list_agents',
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        }
    }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.receivedData = JSON.parse(data);
    });
});
})();
```

And in this above code I used with and without JSON.parse function. Didn't got the correct result.

Here is my view;

```
<section class="content" ng-app="agentApp" ng-controller="agentAddController">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Manage Agents</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="agents_table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sl No.</th>
                            <th>Agent Name</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <div ng-repeat="data in receivedData">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                                <td>{{ data.agent_name }}</td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sl No.</th>
                            <th>Agent Name</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

I know if I put ng-repeat inside tr tag I'll get the perfect result, but I don't want to do that because, I'm working with adminLTE. So there is a function DataTable() in adminLTE where it'll apply search and pagination to the table. If I give ng-repeat to tr, these functionalities can not be added.

Comment: could you show a code where and how you use `DataTable()` where you use search and pagination?

Comment: I'll just give $('#agents_table').DataTable(); in the script and it'll add those functionalities.

Comment: What error do you see in `Console` of browser if you add `ng-repeat` to `tr` and `DataTable()`? I mean it is better to use `ng-repeat` in `<tr/>` than in `<div/>`. Maybe it is better to solve a problem, but not creating other ways.  If you use `<div/>`, then all `div's` will be placed in next row.

Comment: I'm not getting any error in console. If I run the codeigniter function I'm getting this [{"id":"1","agent_name":"Flipkart"},{"id":"2","agent_name":"PayTM"},{"id":"3","agent_name":"Amazon"}] as output

Comment: And one more thing, if I use ng-repeat in tr the problem I'm getting is, in db there are only 3 fields but in view I'm getting 5 rows.. This is so irritating pls help me out

Comment: Set `debugger` before `$scope.receivedData = JSON.parse(data);`  and see why you have 5 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131039/discussion-between-raghu-acharya-and-stepup).

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$scope.receivedData = JSON.parse(data.data);`

The response object is not only the data itself, that's why the 5 rows. It gives back, `data, headers, status, etc...`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: After `then(...)`, chain another method: `.catch(function(err) { console.log(err)})` and see what happened. I think you are requesting json, but the server probably sends `text/html`. In this case you should send it with proper headers, see: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::set_content_type